# Error writing large matrix using R ff

Tags: r, matrix, ff

I've tried to generate a matrix using ff package, but I get the following error:

```
Matrixff <- ff(0, dim = c(1000, 10000))
Error in splitPathFile(x) : 
4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: Not able to reproduce the error with `ff_2.2-13` and `R 3.2.0`

Comment: I'm using  ff_2.2-13 and R 3.2.0  too.

Comment: Then, I don't know why you are getting error.  Have you tried this on a fresh R console with `ff` only loaded?

Comment: Yes, I've tried but it didn't work.

Comment: I am also using linux mint 17

Comment: I am using windows 7

Comment: Ok, I saw that you upgraded and it works.   So, all is good, right?

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded my version of R to R 3.2.1 and it works.