# Creating distance matrix in R for a matrix in a higher dimensional space

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

I have created an euclidean distance matrix using `dist()` function in **`R`**.
Below is my `R` script. As the dimensions of matrix would be `16809 * 16809` while running this script in `R` I got the error message:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.1 Gb

So is there any way to get rid of this error?

I haven't used parallelization in `R` previously. Can it be done using parallelization?

```
rnd.points = matrix(runif(3 * 16809), ncol = 3)
rnd.points <- rnd.points[1:5,]
ds <- dist(rnd.points)
as.matrix(ds) -> nt
nt
```

Comment: A square matrix requires n-squared memory. What can anyone / anything do? :)

Comment: Parallelism won't really help if you need to bring all those distance values to one place and store them.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456639/efficient-memory-wise-function-for-repeated-distance-matrix-calculations-and-c

Comment: perhaps of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190214/dist-function-with-large-number-of-points

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error writing large matrix using R ff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30966925/error-writing-large-matrix-using-r-ff)

Answer (score 1):

As @Gopola said:  `dist(.)` computes all pairwise distances, and hence needs
O(n^2) memory.  Indeed, `dist()` is efficient and only stores *half* of the symmetric  n x n matrix.

If I compute dist() on a computer with enough RAM, it works nicely, and indeed creates an object `ds`  of size 1.1 Gb ... which is not *so* large for today's computers.

```
rnd.points <- matrix(runif(3 * 16809), ncol = 3)
ds <- dist(rnd.points)
object.size(ds)
```

Note however that your

```
as.matrix(ds) -> nt
```

is not such a good idea as the resulting matrix `nt` is indeed (almost) twice the size of `ds`, as `nt` *is* of course a  n x n matrix.

Comment: I want to create a network from the distance matrix. So for creating a network i want a square matrix that should be my adjacency matrix and based on that matrix i will create a network.

Answer (score 0):

O/S has a **principal limit** on `RAM`-addressing ( smaller for a 32-bit system, larger for 64-bit system )
O/S next has a **design-based limit** for a max `RAM` a process can allocate ( +`kill`-s afterwards )

---

### Had the same `InRAM` constraints in python and went beyond that

Sure, at some cost, but was a worth piece of experience.

python `numpy` has a wonderfull feature for this very scenario **seamlessly** inbuilt - a `.memmap()`. The word seamlessly is intentionally emphasised, as this is of the core importance for your problem re-formulation / re-design costs. There are tools available, but it will be your time to master 'em and to re-design your algoritm ( libraries et al ) so as these can use the new tools - guess what - **SEAMLESSLY**. This is the hidden part of the iceberg.

---

### Handy `R` tools available:

- **`filebacked.big.matrix`** which also supports an HPC cluster-wide sharing for distributed processing ( thus solving both **`PSPACE`** **and** **`PTIME`** dimensions of the HPC processing challenge, unless you fortunately hit the filesystem `fileSize` ceiling )
- **`ff`** which allows
  `library(ff)`
  `pt_coords <- ff( vmode = "double", dim = c(16809, 3), initdata = 0 )`
  `pt_dists  <- ff( vmode = "double", dim = c(16809, 16809), initdata = -1 )`
  and work with it in as simple as in matrix-alike `[row,column]` mode to fill in the points and process their pair-wise distances et al,
  `?ffsave` for further details on saving your resulting distances data

and last, but not least

- `mmap` + indexing

---

### [Parallel? No.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/parallel-processing/info)
Distributed?
Yes, might help with **`PTIME`**:

As noted with `filebacked.big.matrix` there are chances to segment the computational `PSPACE` into smaller segments for distributed processing and reduction of the `PTIME`, but the concept is in principle just a concurrent (re)-use of available resouces, not the [ PARALLEL ] system-behaviour ( while it is necessary to admit, that lot of marketing ( the bad news is that even the technology marketing has joined this unfair and knowingly incorrect practice ) texts mis-uses the word parallel / parallelism in places, where a just concurrent system-behaviour is observed ( there are not many real, true-PARALLEL, systems ) ).

---

### Conclusion:

Big matrices are doable in **`R`** well beyond the **`InRAM`** limits, select the tools most suitable for your problem-domain and harness all the HPC-resources you may.

> `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.1 Gb` **is solved.**

There is nothing but resources, that imposts limits and delays on our computing-ready tasks, so do not hesitate to make your move while computing resources are still available for your Project, otherwise you will find yourself, with all the re-engineered software ready, but waiting in a queue for the computing resources.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge. What is ff here is it an inbuilt function in R..?

Comment: I want to find a distance matrix of uniformly distributed 16809 points in 3D space. So how can i achieve it using big.matrix. Can you provide an example R code what you have explained.

Comment: **`library(ff)`** is the answer for the first comment and updated the text, check the library documentation, both for `ff` and `filebacked.big.matrix` for the libraries syntax details. Euclidean distance in R^3? Elementary.

Comment: Yes euclidean distance in R^3. How to associate distance matrix and feed its points in to ff matrix.?

Comment: Dear @seemaaswani StackOverflow is not a do-my-homework site. **Your indicated MCVE error was solved** to a reasonable level of details, incl. alternative ways to direct your further Project development. **StackOverflow does not consider a practice of "give me a code" as a fair Community relation.** Develop your further efforts in directions necessary to extend your achievents ( ref. also to your duplicate attempts to ask for a code for the Euclidean distance in other post  >>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549154/code-to-generate-3d-random-geometric-graph-in-r )

Comment: OK. The question i asked was not to feed total solution for my problem but a solution which i can find for my problem.. The link you shared in above comment was the attempt i have provided previously. In the post it self i have asked about whether its right way of doing it or not. As i am not that strong in coding. As the stack overflow community has wide number of experts my questions are always aimed to have some kind of suggestion or solution not for do my homework or feed me a full code.